# modify html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replace, href

I have a problem with a plugin which I couldn't fixed.
I have this kind of links generated, they all have the same wrong structure but not the same href.

```
<div class="button-float"
<a class="buy" target="_blank" href="<a href="http://www.google.fr" target="_blank" class="buy"></a>">

    € 1,29 

</a>
</div>
```

I'm searching for a solution to get a working href link instead, using jquery, the result should be this :

```
   <div class="button-float"
    <a class="buy" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.fr">

        € 1,29 

    </a>
    </div>
```

I can't find a solution, can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you not use a different plugin? That's some seriously broken HTML.

Comment: Why can't you use a different plugin?

Comment: my client bought this plugin and i can't change it unfortunatly...